# How to have both submit and new line on the soft keyboard for a TextField

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a way to get the enter button on the soft keyboard for a multiline TextField to both submit and dismiss (by pressing enter) and creating a new line (by pressing shift-enter), pretty much the way most of the messaging apps (like whatsapp) are doing.

Is that even possible with the current TextField?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to submit:

`TextField( textInputAction: TextInputAction.go ... )`

and this to unfocus keyboard:

`onFieldSubmitted: (v){ FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus); },`